# Woocommerce change the shipping cost related with the subtotal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know how can i change the shipping cost for example:

If subtotal is lower than 10€ then shipping cost is 4.5€
if subtotal is same or higher than 10€ then make the shipping cost 2.5€

Comment: i found this solution!
https://www.iftekhar.net/blog/how-to-add-flat-rate-shipping-based-on-cart-subtotal-in-woocommerce/

Comment: in that link, what it shows is not really shipping fee. That's additional fee named as Shipping.

Comment: Here you got everything to make it: https://calebburks.com/customize-woocommerce-shipping-rates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way of doing it is like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

    $new_cost = ( WC()->cart->subtotal < 10 ) ? 4.5 : 2.5;

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $rates[$key]->cost = $new_cost;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

more about it [here](http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/woocommerce-shipping-fee-changes-condition-met/).